# How filter using crossfilter in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to filter my dataset using `crossfilter` but with no luck (the full result is returned in my `filterType` var). My code appears to be inline with similar examples online but I must be missing something obvious. The data is for my newborn's sleep patterns, hence this may be contributing to my demise.

Can anyone enlighten me on my oversight?

```
//Load sample sleep data
var dataset = [
  {day: 1, type: 'day', totalSleep: 8},
  {day: 1, type: 'night', totalSleep: 7},
  {day: 2, type: 'day',totalSleep: 8},
  {day: 2, type: 'night', totalSleep: 7}
];

//Crossfilter data
var cf = crossfilter(dataset);

//Create type dimension
var typeDim = cf.dimension(function(d) {return d.type});

//Reduce type by sleep
var sleepByType = typeDim.group().reduceSum(item => item.totalSleep);

//Display result
var allTypes = sleepByType.all();
console.log('All types:');
console.log(allTypes);

//Filter on type
typeDim.filter('day');

//Filtered result
var filterTypes = sleepByType.all();
console.log('Filtered types:');
console.log(filterTypes);
```

Comment: always useful to create a jsfiddle to get people to help. Noone wants to have to figure out which library to load etc.

Comment: Also you might be reinventing the wheel if you're trying to build d3 graphs and filter with crossfilter. Have you had a look at https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/ ?

Comment: It's for a school assignment which restricts usage of libraries to d3.js and crossfilter.js. I'm aware there's an element of reinvention in this method, as dc.js is a nice wrapper for these.  Unfortunately that's the straight-jacket I've been given!

Comment: Figured it out - turns out I needed double quotes for my `filter` parameter, i.e. `typeDim.filter("day")` as opposed to `typeDim.filter('day')`.  Now I know - thanks!

Comment: There isn't any difference between single and double quotes in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

By design, [a group does not observe its own dimension's filters](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#a-group-does-not-observe-its-dimensions-filters).

This is because you usually don't want a chart to filter out its own data. For example, except in rare cases, if you brush an area of the x axis of a line chart, you wouldn't want the line outside the brush to fall to zero.

If you create another dimension on the same field, and filter that, you will see an effect on `sleepByType`:

```
var typeDim2 = cf.dimension(function(d) {return d.type});
typeDim2.filter('day');
```